# Show Hide based on specific ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to show certain li based on id for example::

```html
  <ul class="category-list">
    <li class="category-btn category-selected" id="a">
        <div>
            <span class="category-icon"></span>
            <h2 class=" category-text">
                All
            </h2>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
    </li>

    <li class="category-btn" id="b">
        <div>
            <span class="category-icon"></span>
            <h2 class=" category-text">
                Compat
            </h2>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
    </li>

    <li class="category-btn" id="c">
        <div>
            <span class="category-icon"></span>
            <h2 class=" category-text">
                Connect
            </h2>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
    </li>

    <li class="category-btn" id="d">
        <div>
            <span class="category-icon"></span>
            <h2 class=" category-text">
                Error
            </h2>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
    </li>

    <li class="category-btn" id="e">
        <div>
            <span class="category-icon"></span>
            <h2 class=" category-text">
                Setup
            </h2>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
    </li>

    <li class="category-btn" id="f">
        <div>
            <span class="category-icon"></span>
            <h2 class=" category-text">
                Maintenance
            </h2>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
    </li>

    <li class="category-btn" id="g">
        <div>
            <span class="category-icon"></span>
            <h2 class=" category-text">
                Comparison
            </h2>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
    </li>

    <li class="category-btn" id="h">
        <div>
            <span class="category-icon"></span>
            <h2 class=" category-text">
                Information
            </h2>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
    </li>

    <li class="category-btn" id="i">
        <div>
            <span class="category-icon"></span>
            <h2 class=" category-text">
               shooting
            </h2>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
    </li>

    <li class="category-btn" id="j">
        <div>
            <span class="category-icon"></span>
            <h2 class=" category-text">
                Warranty
            </h2>
        </div>
        <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Now on page load only 3 `<li>` with specific **id = 'b'**, **id = 'e'**, **id = 'f'** should be shown rest will be Hidden, and while clicking on show/hide button all should show up.

Took reference from :[w3 school Read more/less](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_read_more)

But Not sure how to Implement this in `<li>` with some random id

Comment: How do you determine that page 3 should be `b,e,f`?  `$(".category-btn").hide().filter("#b,#e,#f").show()` would work for this scenario.  You'd need to convert "b,e,f" to "#b,#e,#f" (or use other, similar code)

Comment: With CSS you can hide elements like this li[id="IDNAME"] { display: none; } https://jsfiddle.net/4jbtcs9w/

Answer (score 0):

JS code-

```
const liArr = document.getElementsByClassName("category-btn");
const liToHideArr = ["b", "e", "f"]; // or any li id here
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", showHideElements("hide"));

function showAll() {
  showHideElements("show");
}

function showHideElements(action) {
  Array.from(liArr).forEach((element) => {
    if (liToHideArr.includes(element.id)) {
      if (action === "hide") element.classList.add("hidden");
      else element.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
  });
}
document.getElementById("showAll").addEventListener("click", showAll);
```

CSS -

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```