# JS Show Hide Toggle Functionality Based on Specific ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to show only 3 list on first time page load i.e. of id = 'b' (Compatibility), 'e' (Install & Setup
), 'g'(Troubleshooting). and then we have a button, on click of that button "Show More and Show Less" functionality will show and it will load all the list and again click on the button it will hide and show only buttons having id - {'b', 'e', 'g'}. (Toggle Functionality)

```html
<ul class="category-list">
  <li class="category-btn category-selected" id="a">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        All
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="b">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Compatibility
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="c">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Error Messages
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="d">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Identify My Product
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="e">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Install & Setup
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="f">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Product Information & Documentation
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="g">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Troubleshooting
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="h">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Warranty & RMA
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

</ul>
<button id="toggleShow"> Show More and Show Less</button>
```

It is continuation of > [Show Hide based on specific ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65949470/show-hide-based-on-specific-id?noredirect=1#comment116617796_65949470)

The Requirement here is

1. On Page we can see only 3 list having id {'b', 'e', 'g'}
2. We have a button, that will work as Toggle button
3. On click of that button it will show all the list and again click on the button will hide the list except id {'b', 'e', 'g'}

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. It is expected that you have done some research efford and attempted to solve the issue on your own? What have you tried so far? What isn't working as expected? This is literally basic JS / jQuery task for which you should find plenty tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There plenty ways in achieveing what you try. By adding classes, cycle through classes...
However without changing ayn of your HTML structure this is proberly the easiest solution to understand for a beginner.

First you add an onclick event trigger to your button: `<button onclick="toggleShow()">`

Then you add a css declaration to hide all the wanted elemens by default by using: `display: none;`

Then you add the simple JS script as below which checks if the elements in question have an inline styling to be displayed `display: block`. If they have, the button will hdie the elements, if not the button will show thsoe elements.

```js
function toggleShow() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a"),
      c = document.getElementById("c"),
      d = document.getElementById("d"),
      f = document.getElementById("f"),
      h = document.getElementById("h");
      
  if (a.style.display === "block") {
    a.style.display = "none";
    c.style.display = "none";
    d.style.display = "none";
    f.style.display = "none";
    h.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    a.style.display = "block";
    c.style.display = "block";
    d.style.display = "block";
    f.style.display = "block";
    h.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#a,
#c,
#d,
#f,
#h {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="category-list">
  <li class="category-btn category-selected" id="a">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        All
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="b">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Compatibility
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="c">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Error Messages
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="d">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Identify My Product
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="e">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Install & Setup
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="f">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Product Information & Documentation
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="g">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Troubleshooting
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

  <li class="category-btn" id="h">
    <div>
      <span class="category-icon"></span>
      <h2 class=" category-text">
        Warranty & RMA
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow-icon"></span>
  </li>

</ul>
<button id="toggleShow" onclick="toggleShow()"> Show More and Show Less</button>
```